# Mips - Array initialization and index value output

Tags: mips

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main() {
     int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

     int b[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

     int f = 0;

     int f1 = 0;

     int h = 0;

     int g = 0;
    
    printf("Please, type a number for g:");

    scanf_s("%d", &g);
    
    printf("Please, type a number for h:");

    scanf_s("%d", &h);
    
    f = -g + b[h];

    f1 = a[b[g] + 1];

    printf("The 1st result is:%d\n", f);

    printf("The 2nd result is:%d\n", f1);


    return 0;
}
```

I want to convert this c language into mips.I tried this, but there was an error. What should I do?

Below is my code

Maybe this code has problem at Array. I'm not used to using it.

Please tell me the problem and solution.

```
.globl main
.data
A:  .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
B:  .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

str1:.asciiz"Please, type a number for g:"
str2:.asciiz"Please, type a number for h:"

str3:.asciiz"The 1st result is:"
str4:.asciiz"The 2nd result is:"

.text
main:

li $v0,4  #print str1
la $a0,str1 #str1
syscall

li $v0, 5 #input g
syscall
move $s1, $v0 #$s1= g 

li $v0,4  #print str2
la $a0,str2 #str2
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s2, $v0 # $s2 = h 


sll $t0,$s2,2 # t0 = 4 * h
add $t0,$t0,$s7 # address of B[h]
lw $t0,0($t0) # t0 = B[h]
sub $s0,$t0,$s1
move $t3,$s0

sll $t0,$s1,2 # t0 = 4 * g
add $t0,$t0,$s7 # t0 = address of B[g]
lw $t0,0($t0) # t0 = B[g]
addi $t0,$t0,1 # t0 = B[g]+1
sll $t0,$t0,2
add $t0,$t0,$s6
lw $s0,0($t0) # f= A[B[g] +1]
move $t4, $s0

li $v0,4  #print str3
la $a0,str3 #str3
syscall

move $a0,$t3
li $v0,1
syscall

li $v0,4  #print str4
la $a0,str4 #str4
syscall

move $a0,$t4
li $v0,1
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

I don't know why there's an error because I'm not very good at mips. Please help me.

Comment: _"there was an error"_. **What** error? You need to explain your problem in a lot more detail.

Comment: Is it the case that you've posted someone else's broken code that you don't understand and want us to do fix it so you can turn it in as your own?

Comment: The result window says "Exception occurred at PC". I don't know what this means.

Comment: This code is mine, not others'. It's